# Get the time a synchronized method has been blocked in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, time, concurrency, synchronization

I have a synchronized method that is called by different threads, whose execution is mutually exclusive between calls to the method of the same object. I want to know, that in the case that the method has been blocked, the amount of time it has been blocked:

```java
public class ManagerImpl implements Manager {

    public synchronized long entrarEnTramo() {
        movesomething()
        // This method must return long type with the time it has been blocked.
        // In the case it isn't blocked it returns -1.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the source code for this method, you could instrument it manually

```
public long entrarEnTramo() {
    long started = System.nanoTime();
    synchronized (this) {
        long taken = System.nanoTime() - started;
        movesomething();
        return taken;
    }
}
```

But note that this does not really tell you if it was blocked at all, just the time.
You can probably tell the difference from the amount of time spent.

If not, you will have to [roll your own lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) (then you can also implement lock timeouts, which `synchronized` doesn't offer).

Comment: Thank you very much, but how could I check that the method has been blocked with a `ReentrantLock` object?

Comment: @margobra8, Re, "how could I check that the method has been blocked with a `ReentrantLock` object?" Same way! Capture a timestamp immediately before attempting to acquire the lock, and capture a second one immediately after acquiring it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! @besmirched

Comment: NOTE: It will take some amount of time to acquire the lock even if it is not contested, and the amount of time it takes may be different depending on whether or not the lock has ever been acquired by more than one thread. You could do experiments to find out a baseline acquire time, and then subtract that out to get a better idea of how much time threads spend actually _waiting_ for other threads.